# Sorting a ListView in C# causing crashes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, listview

I'm attempting to sort a ListView using C#, but whenever I click the sort button it crashes the webpage. Here's my ASP.NET code:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="list" runat="server" OnSorting="list_Sorting">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Sorter" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="DispName" Text="Display Name" />
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("DispName") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

And here's my C# list_Sorting method:

```
protected void list_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortColumn = e.SortExpression;
    SortDirection sortDirection= (SortDirection) e.SortDirection;
    list.Sort(sortColumn, sortDirection);
    list.DataBind();
}
```

Why is it crashing when I try to sort this?

There is no exception, it just says: "WebDev.WebServer.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close."

Comment: Could you add the Exception message please?

Comment: It's crashing because you're doing something wrong ...   Seriously, you'll have to add more details (like what kind of exception was thrown, etc...) in order to get helpfull answers.

Comment: When you say crashing, I assume you mean it's giving you an exception, what's the exception?

Comment: Ok, no exception; can you check your event log and see if there are any clues there as to what happened?  There's nothing here that should cause the web server to crash, so I suspect there's something else going on.

Comment: **FOR TESTING ONLY**: Add a `Try {} Catch(Exception ex) {}` around the sorting method and have it use `Response.Write(ex.ToString())` to output the exception and paste that for us.

Comment: Tried adding the try-catch around the sorting method, but it still crashed the web server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The Sorting event is raised when a Sort button is clicked or the Sort method is called

```
protected void list_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
{
     ...
     list.Sort(sortColumn, sortDirection);
     ...
}
```

infinite loop

Comment: I wish I could give you +10 points up.  This bug crashed my entire service to a point I had to restart my machine and drove me nuts as to why it's behaving this way. I threw a counter in there because I could not believe it.  Sure enough, infinite loop. Thank you!